# how can i print reverse of a big 10 digit number by using arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, reverse

I've been trying to code a function to print the reveres version of a utmost 10 digit number **by using arrays**...but the problem here is that my code can't print the reverse of a big 10 digit number (like 9999999999 or 9784562312) correctly... I can't find out where the problem is!!
Anyone have an opinion? (sorry if I had Grammatical error, I'm not a native speaker)

and here is the code:

```
int main(){

    const int size = 10;    
    int number, revers;
    
    cin >> number;
    revers = inverse( number, size );
    cout<<revers;
}


int inverse( int n, int size){

    int sum=0, array[size]={0}, i=0;
        
        for( i=0 ; n>=1 ; i++ ){
            
            array[i] = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
    
    int l=i;
        i--;
    
    for(int j=0 ; j<l ; j++, i--){
        sum += pow(10,i)*array[j];
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Range of `int` is `-2147483648`  to  `2147483647` -- use a larger type like `uint64_t` or `int64_t` if you need a signed value.

Comment: `std::string` is an array.

Comment: You don't need an array. (And you should not use `pow` with integer problems.)

Comment: i also wrote it without array but i was just wondering why it's not working like this..

Answer (score 2):

You should be using something like `unsigned long long` instead of `int`, because the value exceeds the maximum int type.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use available functions provided by the standard library. The `std::string` data type is an array, if you insist on it:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void printr(std::uint64_t x) {
  std::string s = std::to_string(x);
  std::reverse(std::begin(s),std::end(s));
  std::cout << s;
}
```